# how to distinguish between 0 and NULL in C

Tags: c

I am trying to print some integer data which includes the integer `0`, but I want to ignore the data containing `NULL` and not print it.
but my C code can't distinguish between `0` and `NULL` and treats them as if they are the same.

```
void ecrire(struct node *p) {
    if (p->data == NULL) {   'if the first node contains NULL it means list is empty'
        printf("no items!\n");
        return;
    }
    struct node *temp = p;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

when I pass a list containing the value 0 in the first node it treats it as if it's an empty list.
any solution Please?

Comment: In most C environments, NULL is defined as zero.  So there's no way to tell the difference.

Comment: What is the type of `data`? Unless it is `int`, the statement `printf("%d ",temp->data)` yields undefined behavior, since `%d` expects this type.

Comment: An empty list is one that has no nodes and whose head pointer is therefore null. If you must use a dummy node, because you think it will make your code easier (but it won't), don't use a special value, but ignore the first node throughout and start the actual list at `head->next`, because if you use a special value you lose the option to use that value as data.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: In old C implementations, `NULL` may be defined as zero. For historical purposes, the C standard allows it to be zero (an integer constant expression with value zero) or zero cast to `void *`. Good C implementations ought to define it as `((void *) 0`, not as `0`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Can `((void *) 0)` be meaningfully distinguished from `0`?

Comment: @SaadOut03 You said "I want to ignore the data containing NULL", but that doesn't quite make sense. You probably meant "I want to ignore the data that is NULL", and you probably want `if(p == NULL) printf("no items!\n");`

Comment: Your `->data` needs to be `int` typed for the `printf("%d",temp->data)`, to work. If it is, trying to compare that with `NULL` is horribly, horribly wrong. You probably want to check whether your list is empty in the second line `if (p==NULL) { puts("no items!"); return; }`, not whether the first node "contains NULL".  The latter would make no sense for int (i.e., nonpointer) data.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yes, of course. They are different types and can be explicitly distinguished with `_Generic` and will trigger various error/warning messages depending on how they are used.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Is that advisable here?  Or is the OP better off with a different algorithm?

Comment: @RobertHarvey It is *certainly* not advisable here!  The OP first needs to be clear on the distinction between the `data` and `next` fields, before worrying about nuances of C null pointers.

Comment: Kinda my point.

Comment: @SteveSummit Yes that was my mistake I didn't know that ''' p==NULL ''' means that it's not pointing to anything and that's what I wanted to check in the first place, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a confusion between testing if the pointer to `struct node` passed to the function is a null pointer and the value of the integer `data` member of the nodes in the list it points to.

`NULL` is used in C as a macro to express a null pointer constant. It is used to test for null pointers. `0` is also a null pointer constant in a pointer context.  Unlike in SQL, there is no concept of a null value representing *no value* in C for numeric values.

Here is a modified version of your code:

```
void ecrire(struct node *p) {
    if (p == NULL) { // if the node pointer is NULL it means list is empty
        printf("no items!\n");
        return;
    }
    struct node *temp = p;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The C standard does not provide for an integer type to represent any values other than integers. There is no null or “NULL” value that means “not any integer value.”

The macro `NULL` is intended for use with pointers, not integers. It is a null pointer constant. For pointers, `NULL` is a value used to indicate the pointer is not pointing at any thing (some object or function). It should not be used with integers. You could use `NULL` with the pointer `p` to determine whether it points to a structure or not, and you could use it with `p->next` to determine whether there is another node linked to the structure.

If the structure may or may not contain data, then generally you should create another member of the structure that indicates whether or not it contains data (and/or possibly how much data or what type of data). Alternatively, you can designate some integer value representable in the type of the `data` member that you will never use for its integer value to be an indicator that there is no data present in the structure.